# Chrome Javascript console defaults to the wrong context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

The context of my Chrome Javascript console always defaults to some random Chrome extension (apparently a different extension each time).   Can I force it to default to the top window?

[image: chrome console]

Comment: Same here, Chrome 52, Windows 10.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue no matter how I launch it  (though usually with cmd+shift+i)

Comment: I *really* wish I could upvote the finding of originals for duplicates. Well done Hackerman and/or Andreas and/or apsillers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637618) already reported as bug in Chrome. So you can check issue status in official bug tracker.

Comment: I signed in and then clicked the star in the “Add comment” section to cast my vote for them to fix. This is a really annoying bug for web development. Thx for linking to the issue @semanser